# Deployment failed in aws beanstalk, getting 502 error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Everything worked in my local, I googled few questions, all have to do with port problem. But since I'm using express, I think I will not have hardcoded port problem, as you can see below is partially the code in

www

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

I have a app.js and below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ..
    ..
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

1. rename app.js to main.js
2. created nodecommand.config file like someone suggested

Answer (score 1):

Create the .zip from the contents, not create a zip from the parent folder.

Hopefully somebody else will find this helpful!